# Error trying to run hokuyo on groovy

Tags: ros, ubuntu, hokuyo-node, ubuntu-quantal, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used ROS for about a month to two months, and before this, I've managed to get hokuyo working fine. But just yesterday, I tried to use it again but failed. I run `roscore`, then in a new terminal, run `rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node`, but I'm faced with an error:

```
[ERROR] [1389842311.466153862]: Exception thrown while opening Hokuyo.
buffer filled without end of line being found (in hokuyo::laser::laserReadline) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting
```

I've seen the troubleshooting page but my error isn't there. I've also tried to uninstall the package using `sudo apt-get remove ros-groovy-laser-drivers` and reinstalling it with `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-laser-drivers` but that didn't help at all.

Would anyone know what happened? I'm just really puzzled because it worked perfectly before.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118401/error-trying-to-run-hokuyo-on-groovy/) by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 324 on 2014-01-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you check your port? In default, hokuyo run on /dev/ttyACM0, do you check whether that port is used by some other device?

Let me know if this helps.

---

Originally posted by [zero1985](https://answers.ros.org/users/6926/zero1985/) with karma: 100 on 2014-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-01-15**:
Thanks it helped! My /dev/ttyACM0 was arduino.